# When creating a button from a Dialog Box

Tags: android, button, dialog

The original code has been deleted, the new working code is shown. The idea behind the code is to create a new textView within a layout that has a custom name to it that the user provides. Previously, a NPE error was happening. This is a fix. Any questions, please feel free to ask.

**EDIT: Found the solution**

The fix needs to be as followed:

```
accountEdit = new EditText(this); // accountEdit needs to be a global variable
```

then within the builder.setPositiveButton

```
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dInterface, int whichButton)
        {

            LinearLayout lineLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

            String newAccountName = accountEdit.getText().toString();

            newTextView = new TextView( getBaseContext()    );


            newTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            newTextView.setText(    newAccountName    );
            newTextView.setId(id);
            newTextView.setTextSize(35);

            newTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    onClickNew(view);
                }
            });
            newTextView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Testing" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

This will create the button, as well as set the name of the button to the information that is in the EditText within the Dialog Box. Previously, the EditText was from another activity, and was being called wrong, which caused the NPE. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Do you have an R.id.newAccountButton in your XML?

Comment: Without looking at all of your code, I will guess that is because dialog has a view, so if you call `findViewById` inside `Dialog` class, it actually calls the dialogView.findViewById instead of your activity findViewById().

Answer (score 0):

As Wenhui metioned, you call the finViewById inside the onclick listener of the button, so the wrong context is used. Do it like in the following example:

```
final EditText accountEdit    =   (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newAccountButton);
final String newAccountName   =   accountEdit.getText().toString();
final LinearLayout lineLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dInterface, int whichButton)
    {
        newTextView = new TextView(getBaseContext());

        newTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        newTextView.setText("Test");
        newTextView.setId(id);
        newTextView.setTextSize(35);

        newTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickNew(view);
            }
        });

        lineLayout.addView(newTextView);
        id++;
    }
});
```